# embed with Slash commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

well i'm learning to code a discord bot with Disocrd.py, but i'm in difficulty fo adding thumbnail, url, author, etc... to an embed summoned by a slash command. did someone can help me ?

here is my code, everything is setuped correctly, i've just vanished names for example :

````
#imports
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("discord_token")

#paramètres
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.streaming, name="name", url = "twitch_url")
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix="!")
blue = discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 0, 200)
red = discord.Color.from_rgb(200, 0, 0)
green = discord.Color.from_rgb(0, 200, 0)
discord_blue = discord.Color.from_rgb(84, 102, 244)

#commands
@tree.command(name = "name", description = "description", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def twitter(interaction):
    emb=discord.Embed(title="title", description="description", color=blue)
    discord.Embed.set_author(name="name", icon_url="url") # type: ignore
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb, ephemeral=True) # type: ignore


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
    if on_ready :
        print("RUNNING")

client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN) # type: ignore```

the real problem is precisely in the slash command module, well here :

```#commands
@tree.command(name = "name", description = "description", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def twitter(interaction):
    emb=discord.Embed(title="title", description="description", color=blue)
    discord.Embed.set_author(name="name", icon_url="url") # type: ignore
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb, ephemeral=True) # type: ignore```

i was trying to specify every field, like the footer, url, author, author_url,... but i don't understand why i doesn't work.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the variable `emb` to the [discord.Embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed) object, you want to use the method [set_author](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_author).

The line `discord.Embed.set_author(name="name", icon_url="url")` is meaningless because you're not using your assigned variable.

In this case you want to set the author of your embed `emb`.

```
@tree.command(name="mycommand")
async def mycommand(interaction):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="title")
    emb.set_author(name="Raymus")
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=emb, ephemeral=True)
```